# Sorting and Saving Tabs + Fields using jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to sort my tabs and I also want to sort the fields inside the tabs. I want to be able to drag the fields from one tab to the other as well.

[image]

When the user clicks on the Save button I want to get a json string. Something similar to the following:

[image]

I did some research and it seems that it is possible using jQuery Sortable (Connect lists with Tabs). Can someone post a decent piece of html+javascript please? Thank you.

The following code I wrote is a disaster.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs().find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            debugger;
        }
    });

    $(".fieldSortableList").sortable().disableSelection();

    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var $tab_items = $("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
        accept: ".connectedSortable li", hoverClass: "ui-state-hover", drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $list = $($item.find("a").attr("href")).find(".connectedSortable");
            ui.draggable.hide("slow", function () {
                $(this).appendTo($list).show("slow");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the "ConnectWith" property when defining the sortable bind. This will allow you to sort/drop items form list a to list b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "ConnectWith" property when defining the sortable bind. This will allow you to sort/drop items form list a to list b.

In order to save their states, you can take the items of the list, save them as array in localStorage, and then compare them to the saved localstorage fields during page load. When you load the page, you compare the current list order, to the saved order, and if different, append them to the new list. When you are done, the new list has all of the items, but in the saved order.

I have not seen API for sortable in a while, but this will also help you out. http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: This looks pretty good.  http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/
I will give it a try today. Thanks Casey.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on jquery-sortable but it wasnt 100% what I wanted; it was 40% what I needed. In the end I went back to my old code and fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds good. This happens a lot to me at my work. Well, not a lot, but sometimes. I have found that just stepping away for a while, then coming back opens new doors you may have been missing, our bios towards trying previously. :)

Comment: very true :) sometimes I deliberately park tasks for a week and even the most difficult of tasks appear simple after some time and then I have 'What didnt I think of that last week?' moment.